# Tools to easily navigate references in research papers

Tags: publications, citations, reference-managers, tools

Often times while reading academic papers, I need to check the citations referred to in the text, and so I naturally end up scrolling to the last page of the paper, finding the appropriate citation, and looking it up on the web. And then scroll all the way back up.
Is there any tool where in I can see the citations of a paper in the sidebar, so I can quickly refer to them while reading the paper.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Different PDF tools have different options. One way is just to have multiple windows open, with one down in the reference section and one where you are reading...

Comment: Why not just open up the pdf in an additional window, where it is scrolled down to the reference list?

Comment: A PDF viewer like Skim on MacOS has a split screen feature that you can use for this.

Comment: I currently do what others have suggested -- have two windows open, one with the paper and one with references. Was wondering if there is a better way than that?
For e.g., a PDF tool where the citations can be shown with a mouse hover, or if I click on it, the citation gets displayed in the sidebar etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your field uses the arXiv, the [arXiv Bibliographic Explorer](https://github.com/mattbierbaum/arxiv-bib-overlay) from [arXivLabs](https://labs.arxiv.org/showcase/) may be useful. It is a browser extension that allows you to view the references and citations for a paper on the arXiv without having to e.g. search for the title of the paper on Google. If you have the PDF opened in one tab and the arXiv page in another, then you can quickly find hyperlinks to relevant papers through the search functionality.